# drupal database data fetch with multiple tables having same column

Tags: php, database, drupal-7

I am trying to fetch the data from multiple tables "having same column names" but it doesn't give me required results in drupal. 
here is my code.

```
$result = db_query ( "select table1.symbol, table2.symbol, table1.price_sales, table2.price_sales from {table1, table2} where table1.uid = table2.uid" );

while ( $obj = $result->fetch () ) {
    echo ($obj->table1.symbol);  // it doesn't return the results
    echo ($obj->table2.symbol);
}
```

Comment: can you do one of the .symbol as something else?

Comment: Yes thanks, I have changed the names of each table but its not a nice solution. There should be a work around for this.

Comment: I also recommend using `db_select` it's a lot cleaner interface IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch()` **is not** a method to the `DatabaseStatementInterface` on `Dupral 7.x`. Try `fetchAllAssoc()` or `fetchAllKeyed()`

See the [DatabaseStatementInterface Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/interface/DatabaseStatementInterface/7.x)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the name of any column when running the query:

```
$result = db_query ( "select table1.symbol as second_symbol, table2.symbol, table1.price_sales, table2.price_sales from {table1, table2} where table1.uid = table2.uid" );

while ( $obj = $result->fetch () ) {
    echo ($obj->table1.second_symbol);
    echo ($obj->table2.symbol);
}
```